# How to make detail band height fixed in Jasper Report?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have two reports. One is used as sub report of other.

Sub-Report is placed in the detail band of main report.

I need to display a message at the end of the last page. For this message, I am using Last Page Footer.

But the problem is, I need to display the data in Tabular Form. Data coming from Sub report is dynamic, Because of this detail band height grows dynamically and I can not get the table lines aligned properly up to the last page footer.

Can anyone guide me a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not getting your point, but if you need something as close as possibile to your last tabular data (not neccesarly at the end of the last page), why don't you use the Summary band instead of the LastPageFooter?

I hope to show you what I mean with this pic:

[image]

Is this what you would like to get?

If so, just use the Summary Band in the main report after your detail band

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Hi Alex, I'm not getting your point... I've suggested just how I would solve that problem using Summary Band... where's the problem? No hate here, just asking clarifications for my answer since I'm new in SOF. Tnx for your time

Comment: I think it would be better to confirm that the OP would like that kind of output in a comment, and if that is the OP's intent, post code to achieve that result in an answer.

Comment: Now I've understood what you mean... I still think that anyway this kind of post doesn't strictly require a "code answer"... well at least, I'd prefer a sample image :-)

Comment: Hi Panto, Thanks for your response. I need to get the report as shown in Multiple pages report version. But a change is, Last Message should always come at the bottom of the page .